# Resize an OpenBSD *fdisk* partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, fdisk, openbsd

I have cloned an OpenBSD qemu image into a physical hard drive and everything works but the fdisk partition dedicated to OpenBSD has the same size it had in the virtual machine and most of the excess disk space out of it gets unused. My disk size is 230GB and I can only use 32GB of it, which was exactly the size of the QEMU qcow2 image. How can I grow the fdisk (not the disklabel) partition dedicated to OpenBSD up to the full drive size?

```
# fdisk -e sd0     
Enter 'help' for information
sd0: 1> p G
Disk: sd0   geometry: 30401/255/63 [488397168 Sectors]
Offset: 0   Signature: 0xAA55
            Starting         Ending         LBA Info:
 #: id      C   H   S -      C   H   S [       start:        size ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0: 00      0   0   0 -      0   0   0 [           0:           0G] Unused
 1: 00      0   0   0 -      0   0   0 [           0:           0G] Unused
 2: 00      0   0   0 -      0   0   0 [           0:           0G] Unused
*3: A6      0   1   2 -   4177  85   4 [          64:          32G] OpenBSD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit and extend it. Disklabel will see the additional space afterwards.

Only extending the end of the partition works this way. You must not change the start offset.

In the example below, I'm extending a partion from 2GB to 4GB:

```
sd0: 1> edit 3
            Starting         Ending         LBA Info:
 #: id      C   H   S -      C   H   S [       start:        size ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*3: A6      0   1   2 -    261  21  48 [          64:     4194272 ] OpenBSD
Partition id ('0' to disable) [01 - FF]: [A6] (? for help)
Do you wish to edit in CHS mode? [n]
Partition offset [0 - 8388607]: [64]
Partition size [1 - 8388544]: [4194272] 8388544
sd0*: 1> w
Writing MBR at offset 0.
sd0: 1>
```

Comment: The only problem is I cannot extend the size to include the unused space. If I try to do that here is what I get:

Partition size [1 - 488397104]: [488397104] 500000000
Partition size is out of range:  500000000

Comment: Not sure what you mean with unused space. The max size of the partiton you're showing is 488397104. That's 100%. Either your disk is not bigger, or there is another partition afterwards.